# occur no matching function for call to error in c++

Tags: c++

I'm a novice in `c++`, i know there is a lot of similar questions but unfortunately didn't help me to solve this problem (which is a conceptual misunderstood i think)

So i have this `constructor`

```
Field::Field(const Position &posG, const Position &posC) {
    //...
}
```

And i am creating a `Field` as follows

```
// Create positions
Position posG, posC;
posG.x = 3;
posG.y = 3;
posC.x = 4;
posC.y = 4;

// Create pointers to positions
const Position *pPosC(&posC);
const Position *pPosG(&posG);

// Create field
Field field (pPosG, pPosC);
```

Where position is

```
struct Position {
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

Then i am getting this exception:

```
main.cpp:27:30: error: no matching function for call to ‘Field::Field(const Position*&, const Position*&)’
     Field Field (pPosG, pPosC);

In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
```

Any help? Regards

Comment: Use `Field field (*pPosG, *pPosC);` or `Field field (posG, posC);` instead.

Comment: // Create field
Field field (*pPosG, *pPosC);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Field(const Position &posG, const Position &posC);
                     ^^^^^                 ^^^^^^
```

Those are references. So when you try to pass pointers

```
Field field (pPosG, pPosC);
             ^^^^^   ^^^^
             pointer   pointer
```

It can't compile.

Either make the constructor accept reference pointers (`const Position *&posG)` or pass the value of the pointers (`*pPosG`), or just pass the values directly (`posG`).

Comment: `posG` and `posC` are just fine. See `Position posG, posC;`.

Comment: @skypjack We are not talking about the same `posG` and `posC` :) But I see your point, thx

Answer (score 3):

When you have a constructor defined as

```
Field(const Position &posG, const Posicion &posC);
```

You can use objects of type `Position` as arguments to it, not pointers to `Position`.

You can use:

```
Field field(posG, posC);
```

or

```
Field field(*pPosG, *pPosC);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your constructor expects references, not pointers.

As a sidenote, it's not clear why you use references or pointers.

Answer (score 0):

you must define a `constructor`, then use of `const Position *pPosC(&posC);` expression.

you must define `constructor-copy` like this :

```
struct Posicion {
public :
    Position(const Position &pos)         // constructor copy
    {
        // some code here
        x = pos.x;
        y = pos.y;
    }

    int x;
    int y;
};
```